# Passing several, optional, key/value pairs in URL with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am making a project management application in Larvel.  TaskController@index queries the db and return tasks. To be efficient and elegant, I want to be able to pass it several, optional, key/value pairs in the URL, like /tasks/org_id/36/status/open or /tasks/proj_id/1557/status/closed, and have it return the tasks based on those variables.  My code is below, but the problem is getting the route to be able to receive the optional key/value pairs.  Also, they shouldn't all have to all be submitted all of the time if they aren't needed.

Route/web.php:

```
Route::get('/tasks/status/{status}/proj_id/{proj_id}/user_id/{user_id}/org_id/{org_id}
/creator_id/{creator_id}', 'TaskController@index')->name('tasks.index');

Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController')->except([
    'tasks.index'
]);
```

Controller:

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function index($proj_id = null, $recipient_id = null, $org_id = null, $creator_id = null, $status = null)
    {

        $tasks = Task::where('recipient_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->when($status, function ($query, $status) {
                return $query->where('status', $status);
            })
            ->when($recipient_id, function ($query, $recipient_id) {
                return $query->where('recipient_id', $recipient_id);
            })
            ->when($public, function ($query, $public) {
                return $query->where('public', $public);
            })
            ->get();

        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
    }
```

How do I get the route to be able to accept a variety of optional key/value pairs?

Comment: Just to note, none of these parameters are optional; they need to have a question mark, like `{param?}` to be so. But that being said, this is just asking for trouble... Chaining optional route parameters will fail as soon as one of them is ignored. Consider changing this to use `POST` logic, or a proper query string, like `?status=status&proj_id=...`

Comment: you can use the question mark.. to set that parameter as optional. /tasks/status/{status?}/proj_id/{proj_id?}/user_id/{user_id?}/org_id/{org_id?}
/creator_id/{creator_id?}

Comment: In all honesty this is probably better suited for GET params.

Answer (score 1):

For your convenience, work with GET (?status=...&...=...) parameters and work through them in a [global middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#global-middleware). It will possibly eliminate a lot of confusion as your project grows.

In the middleware you could do something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $params = array();

        //OR look them up individually:
        $params['status'] = $request->query('status');
        $params['proj_id'] = $request->query('proj_id');
        $params['org_id'] = $request->query('org_id');

        //OR get all query requests at once:
        $params = $request->query();

        //and set them as a session value
        $request->session()->put('params', $params);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Access the possible values anywhere in the project with the helper `session('params')['status']`. If there is no value in the url, it's defaulted to `null`.

*Addition*: to help you out building the query params for the url you may want to have a look at the PHP function [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
i think fix your problem

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController')->except([
    'index'
]);

Route::get('/tasks/status/{status}/proj_id/{proj_id}/user_id/{user_id}/org_id/{org_id}
/creator_id/{creator_id}', 'TaskController@index');
```

i hope help you

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/routeresource-parameters